# my form cannot receive request.files. I have a problem that user profile photo cannot be uploaded. img is sent trough request method properly

Tags: python, django

** views.py **

```
def create_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfile(request.POST)
        user_photo = PhotoUser(request.FILES,request.POST) #instance=request.user.userphoto
        print(request.FILES) * here i can see my image went trough *
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    else:
        form = UserProfile()
        user_photo = PhotoUser()
    return render(request,'user/user.html',{'form':form,'user_photo':user_photo})
```

** urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.exe,name='exe'),
    path('books/', include('books.urls')),
    path('user/', include('user.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

** signals.py**

```
@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserPhoto.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.userphoto.save()
```

** models.py **

```
class UserPhoto(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_directory_path,default='avatar.png',blank=True,null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

** html**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    {{user_photo}}
    <input type="file" name="img" accept="image/*" id="id_img">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

**forms.py**

```
class PhotoUser(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserPhoto
        fields = ['img']
```

```
MEDIA_ROOT = (BASE_DIR / 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

so everything works ok but users profile images are not getting uploaded.

signals are executed properly and 2 models are conected and my avatar.png is uploaded to every user and user is saved.

if i upload user photo via admin it works properly

Answer (score 0):

Please *remove* the signal to create a `UserPhoto`, it will result in the fact that the form and the signal try to create both a `UserPhoto`, and therefore either one of the two will fail, in this case that will be the `PhotoUser` form. Furthermore, [using Signals, often result in problems](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html), and only in specific cases these are effective.

You can implement a view that will create a `UserPhoto` that is linked to the logged in user:

```
# remove the create_profile signal

def create_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfile(request.POST)
        user_photo = PhotoUser(request.FILES, request.POST) #instance=request.user.userphoto
        if form.is_valid() and user_photo.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user_photo.instance.user = user
            user_photo.save()
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')

    else:
        form = UserProfile()
        user_photo = PhotoUser()
    return render(request,'user/user.html',{'form':form,'user_photo':user_photo})
```

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

Comment: thanks for quick response. well i will do your way then. i just to wanted to know how to do this with signals but if  its not the best idea i will move on

Comment: @mg777: but you signal simply runs when you *create* a user. Since there is no way to specify a file as profile image, it will thus use the default `avatar.png`. If then the form with the photo is used (the `PhotoUser` model), then it can not make a new object, since then there are two `UserPhoto`s that refer to the same user.

Comment: @mg777: because from the moment you create a user, the signal will run, constructing a `UserPhoto`. Since your signal did not specify a specific file, it will use the *default* value, so `avatar.png`. Then, after the user is saved and the signal has created a `UserPhoto`, the form of that `UserPhoto` (`PhotoUser`) will run, and try to create a `UserPhoto` as well, but since the `user = ...` field is a `OneToOneField`, that means it can not create such a record, hence it will fail.

Comment: I did not know it works that way, even now it dosent make sense yet to me too much. why userphoto  uses a default avatar if my form already recived files(image) in views.py, then i execute save method on my first form model, then signal is triggered to execute connection betwen 2 models and save it,  but my photouser had already recived the image trough views.py

Comment: @mg777: because the signals work independent of views. Since the signal runs immediately *after* creating a user, there is no way the signal can now that you uploaded a file, nor set that file as the `UserPhoto` of that user.

Comment: I am confused, i think i get you.  save method is executed in views to trigger signals  but that has nothing to do with the views.py? so signal is triggered because i preform save method on my first form model.

Comment: @mg777: indeed, so when you save a `User` object, you create a simpel `UserPhoto` object for that user, with the `avatar`. Next the `PhotoUser` form, aims to create a `UserPhoto` as well, with the uploaded image, but fails to do so, since there is already a `UserPhoto` record for that user.